# Firebase returns object to local storage on sign in but how do I access it?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase

On a successful sign in on firebase it returns an object and stores it in local storage. However the key is very long as seen below:

"firebase:authUser:AIzaSyAD5OqcuGExhWi_oASzr42rq5IVvR7jdCY:[DEFAULT]"

How do I access the value associated to this?

Also I do not know if this key will be the same for every person logging on.

Comment: It looks like that's just the app identifier or user identifier string. I can't be sure and also don't know what you're looking to accomplish (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). If you can edit your question to add some code and a clear description of your goal, it would probably be clearer how we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript object `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.getItem("firebase:authUser:AIzaSyAD5OqcuGExhWi_oASzr42rq5IVvR7jdCY:[DEFAULT]");
```

this will return a String, so I suggest to parse it as a JSON object:

```
var storedData = JSON.parse(
   localStorage.getItem("firebase:authUser:AIzaSyAD5OqcuGExhWi_oASzr42rq5IVvR7jdCY:[DEFAULT]")
);
```

The String will be the same for every user logging in because `AIzaSyAD5OqcuGExhWi_oASzr42rq5IVvR7jdCY` is the ApiKey of your application and `[DEFAULT]` its name.